# What is the python equivalent of the Perl pattern to track if something has already been seen?

Tags: python, perl

In Perl, one can do the following

```
for (@foo) {
    # do something 
    next if $seen{$_}++;
}
```

I would like to be able to do the equivalent in Python, that is to skip a block if it has been executed once.

Comment: You know how to skip the current iteration of a loop in Python, yes? You also know how to use hashes in Python? And how to use conditionals? You can just put that all together and you have your solution.

Comment: Anon, no, I do not which is why I am asking. "next if $seen{$_}++" nicely expresses what I am trying to do and it seems that the python equivalents seem not as elegant. Although itertools seems that it might fit the bill per Greg.

Comment: Perhaps by "elegant" you mean "concise" or "terse"? It's ok if for you terse/concise means elegant, since beauty is in the eye of the beholder, however please refrain from using subjective conditions whenever you request help from others; you and only you know what is elegant for you.

Comment: After 10 years with Python I never have needed any "seen" function, which is probably why it's not there. I don't know enough Perl to actually understand what your code example does, so I can't tell you what the easiest way of doing it is in Python. But I suspect that trying to translate a specific Perl thingy into Python "word by word" isn't gonna work very well. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
seen = set()
for x in foo:
    if x in seen:
        continue
    seen.add(x)
    # do something
```

See the [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) documentation for more information.

Also, the examples at the bottom of the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module documentation contains a `unique_everseen` generator that you can use like this:

```
for x in unique_everseen(foo):
    # do something
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like unique_everseen might fit the bill although it seems to be listed as an optional recipe instead of being part of the module.

Comment: jnman, don't let anyone force Python on you. I mean, from the way you choose to write your comments, it's obvious that you find Python at best a necessary evil (perhaps it's a job requirement) and its library severely lacking (contrary to, say, the magnificent CPAN).

Comment: I am much more comfortable using perl than python. However, due to some stuff that I am currently working on, I have to use python instead hence the questions. It just seems that this particular perl(ism) is sufficiently useful (to me) that I am somewhat surprised that there is no equivalent "terse" version in python (to use your words).

Comment: @jnman - Python and terse usually don't go together. If you want terse, stick with Perl. I bet money CPAN has a package to do whatever "stuff you're currently working on" that you're using Python for. (I like (and dislike) both languages, but I am a bit biased towards Perl since it's my native tongue, so to speak.)

Answer (score 1):

```
seen={}
for item in foo:
   if seen.has_key(item):
      seen[item]+=1
      continue # continue is optional, just to illustrate the "next" in Perl
   else:
      seen[item]=1
```

Comment: Alternatively `from collections import defaultdict; seen = defaultdict(int); for item in foo: seen[item] += 1; if seen[item] > 1: continue; #rest of code` (with proper indentation, of course.)

Comment: yes, +1 for that. But I guess i am still old school, so this works for version <2.4+

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the order of the things in foo, and only that the unique items are iterated over, then the solution is *much* simpler.

```
for x in set(foo):
    do something
```